# How to log memory consumption of a windows process with perfmon?

Tags: windows, perfmon

I am new to perfmon and I am trying to use that tool to check the memory consumption of a given, single process (in order to check for memory leaks) in Windows 7.

In `perfmon` I have created a new DataCollector and trying to add a new counter. In the `Available counter` list I see the entry `Process` which has several sub-counters (like, for example, 'Handle Count'), from which I can select an instance of a process I would like to be monitored. But in the list of sub-counters (under process) I do not find a field called 'Memory' or something.

However, in the `Available counter` list there is also an entry named 'Memory', which has several sub-entries. But no matter which of these sub-entries to choose, there is no instance I can select from!

So how can I select to monitor the memory consumption for a given process then? Is it hidden behind some other counter / sub-counter?

Answer (score 0):

The counters below **Memory** are about physical RAM and physical RAM is related to the computer, not to processes. Therefore, there's nothing else to select. You can see that if you turn on the description:

[image: Perfmon Description of memory]

Instead, your choice regarding **Process** was not too bad. If you look at the end of that list, you'll find virtual memory related information

[image: Perfmon about virtual memory]